# Importing text files to xlsm, then overwriting sheetname if already exists

Tags: vba, excel

After hours of failed googled VB scripts, I thought I'd come here.

Currently I have modified a VBA script which imports multiple txt files, and copies them to new sheets in an XLSM file, according to the txt file name.

I want to do 2 things, which {solved} answers on google just don't seem to working for me.

1) overwrite an existing sheet if it already exists --- (NB: not delete it... it will be linked to another sheet for calculations), and

2) import the text file in space delimited format --- again, solved answers not playing the game.

Thanks (ps -- There are several similar questions here, some have similar solved answers to my question, but seem much more convoluted... I'm after something as simple as possible)

```
Sub GetSheets()
Path = "C:\test\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.txt")
Do While Filename <> ""
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Next Sheet
Workbooks(Filename).Close
Filename = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem a while ago, with similar constraint as your 1st :
 - keep the sheet because of references pointing there

However I didn't have your 2nd constraint, therefore I can't tell if it matches 100% ; however I'm pretty sure you can work it through. I would even suggest that you perform the import query to a temporary sheet, and then use a copy-paste macro operation to move your *well-defined* range to its final destination

I solved it using a query for the import. I came to this using the "Macro recorder" to do "csv import" ; then I refactored the code.

```
' @brief ImportFile : Opens specified file and imports contents at destination
' @param ImpFileName : Path to the file to import
' @param ImpDest : Location of the destination (must be a single cell range)

Private Sub ImportFile(ImpFileName As String, ImpDest As Range)
 With ImpDest.Worksheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
  "TEXT;" & ImpFileName, Destination:=ImpDest)
  .Name = "Import"
  .FieldNames = True
  .RowNumbers = False
  .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
  .PreserveFormatting = True
  .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
  .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
  .SavePassword = False
  .SaveData = True
  .AdjustColumnWidth = True
  .RefreshPeriod = 0
  .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
  .TextFilePlatform = 65001
  .TextFileStartRow = 1
  .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
  .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
  .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
  .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
  .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
  .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
  .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
  .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1)
  .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
  .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
 End With
 ' As the query execution does not trigger "content change event", we force triggering
 ' by editing the 1st cell's content.
 Dim MyVal As Variant
 MyVal = ImpDest.Cells(1, 1).Value
 ImpDest.Cells(1, 1) = MyVal

End Sub
```

You might want to change some of the query options to fit your need.

NB: The three last lines are there to fix a bug (or something that looked like a bug) : The query execution does not trigger "calculate" event on the referees.